# debian dh-exec install creates extra directory

Tags: debian, package, debhelper

I'm building a debian package that installs several config files to different places with other names. For that I wanted to use `dh-exec` install-rename capabilities.

In the *control* file I declared `dh-exec` as *Build-Dependency*:

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), dh-exec
```

The `package.install` file looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/dh-exec
default.pdns.conf => /etc/powerdns/pdns.conf
default.uwsgi.ini => /etc/resolver/uwsgi.ini
default.config.toml => /etc/resolver/config.toml
default.nginx.conf => /etc/nginx/sites-available/resolver.conf
```

I expected this to deploy the existing `default.*` files in those places with that names, but instead a parent directory is created containing the file as it was:

```
/etc/resolver/
|-- config.toml
|   `-- default.config.toml
`-- uwsgi.ini
    `-- default.uwsgi.ini
```

The same happens for all declared files.

No overrides in the `debian/rules` files that might interfere with this:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

export DH_VERBOSE=1

%:
    dh $@ --with systemd,python-virtualenv


 override_dh_virtualenv:
    dh_virtualenv --package resolver --python /usr/bin/python3
```

When setting `DH_VERBOSE=1` this is what the `dh_install` helper does:

```
   dh_install
        install -d debian/resolver//etc/powerdns/pdns.conf
        cp --reflink=auto -a ./default.pdns.conf debian/resolver//etc/powerdns/pdns.conf/
        install -d debian/resolver//etc/resolver/uwsgi.ini
        cp --reflink=auto -a ./default.uwsgi.ini debian/resolver//etc/resolver/uwsgi.ini/
        install -d debian/resolver//etc/resolver/config.toml
        cp --reflink=auto -a ./default.config.toml debian/resolver//etc/resolver/config.toml/
        install -d debian/resolver//etc/nginx/sites-available/resolver.conf
        cp --reflink=auto -a ./default.nginx.conf debian/resolver//etc/nginx/sites-available/resolver.conf/
```

I feel like I'm missing something really stupid here. 
After inspecting the `dh-exec` documentation and code, I think there must be something weird between `dh-exec` output and `dh-install` run.

I'd appreciate any tips on this.

Versions:

- dh-exec 0.22
- debhelper 9.20160115ubuntu
- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `package.install` file needs to be **executable**.

Otherwise *dh-exec* won't run and it will be used as a regular *.install* file.
For a regular *.install* file, `=>` are not found files, thus ignored, and the right member is a directory to be created, not a destination file.

I finally figured out this by myself by checking other projects that use *dh-exec*.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it didn't work until I updated `debian/compat` to level `9`.